# How to know a Bytebuf was read from which channel in Netty4?

Tags: netty, channel

When the `channelRead()` is called, I need to know the data was read from which channel(I have several child channel).

In Netty3, we can attach an object to the Channel or `ChannelHandlerContext` when `channelConnected` is called,then tell the channel from attachment(Is there a better way?).

But in Netty4, I can not find such a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach some attribute via

```
channel.attr(key).set(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `channel.hashCode();` and recover the channel from a `channelGroup` object.